Seekbar onProgressChanged not working properly (Android)
I am here providing my adapter class which is having the seekbar slider. It works only on thumb click on the slider but not onDragging.
package com.welbornindia.app.ui.adapter.device1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.CircleCrop;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.welbornindia.app.MyApplication;
import com.welbornindia.app.R;
import com.welbornindia.app.config.BaseConfig;
import com.welbornindia.app.config.device1.Config_1;
import com.welbornindia.app.config.device2.Config_2;
import com.welbornindia.app.config.device3.Config_3;
import com.welbornindia.app.domain.DeviceInfo;
import com.welbornindia.app.domain.device1.DeviceBasicProperties_1;
import com.welbornindia.app.domain.device2.DeviceBasicProperties_2;
import com.welbornindia.app.domain.device3.DeviceBasicProperties_3;
import com.welbornindia.app.domain.device4.DeviceBasicProperties_4;
import com.welbornindia.app.ui.view.MyGridView;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public
/**
 * @author       :xuzip
 * date          :2022/3/11 10:32
 */
class ScenesItemAdapter_1 extends BaseAdapter {
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfos = new ArrayList<>();

    public ScenesItemAdapter_1(Context context, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.context = context;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public void setDeviceInfos(List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfos){
        this.deviceInfos = deviceInfos;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return deviceInfos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return deviceInfos.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView device_img;
        TextView device_name;


        TextView tv_white_light_brightness;
        SeekBar sb_white_light_brightness;
        TextView tv_ipl_light_brightness;
        SeekBar sb_ipl_light_brightness;

        TextView tv_ipl_light_saturation_1;
        SeekBar sb_ipl_light_saturation;
        TextView tv_white_light_color_temperature;
        SeekBar sb_white_light_color_temperature;
        TextView tv_ipl_h;
        SeekBar sb_color;
        TextView tv_group;
        ImageView iv_close;

        RelativeLayout rel_ipl_brightness;
        RelativeLayout rel_temp;

        RelativeLayout rel_ipl_saturation;
        RelativeLayout rel_ipl_color;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int select, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_scene_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.device_img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_img);
            holder.device_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);

            holder.tv_white_light_brightness = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_white_light_brightness);
            holder.sb_white_light_brightness = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sb_white_light_brightness);

            holder.tv_white_light_color_temperature = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_white_light_color_temperature);
            holder.sb_white_light_color_temperature = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sb_white_light_color_temperature);


            holder.tv_ipl_light_brightness = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ipl_light_brightness);
            holder.sb_ipl_light_brightness = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sb_ipl_light_brightness);

            holder.tv_ipl_light_saturation_1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ipl_light_saturation_1);
            holder.sb_ipl_light_saturation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sb_ipl_light_saturation);


            holder.tv_ipl_h = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ipl_h);
            holder.sb_color = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sb_color);



            holder.tv_group = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
            holder.iv_close = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_close);


            holder.rel_ipl_brightness = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel_ipl_brightness);
            holder.rel_temp = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel_temp);

            holder.rel_ipl_saturation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel_ipl_saturation);
            holder.rel_ipl_color = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rel_ipl_color);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //关键代码
        if (viewGroup instanceof MyGridView) {
            if (((MyGridView)viewGroup).isOnMeasure) {
                return convertView;
            }
        }


        int w_brightness = 100;
        int w_temperature = 100;

        int i_brightness = 100;

        int i_saturation = 100;
        int i_color = 100;

        int selectGroup = 1;
        int selectChannel = 1;
        final boolean[] open = {false};

        int cct_max = 85;
        int cct_min = 25;

        holder.sb_white_light_brightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean check) {
                Log.e("白光 亮度",progress+"  "+ check);
                holder.tv_white_light_brightness.setText(progress+"%");
                if(check){
                    if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,0,progress);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        holder.sb_white_light_color_temperature.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean check) {
                Log.e("白光 色温",progress+"  "+ check);
                holder.tv_white_light_color_temperature.setText(progress+"00K");
                if(check){
                    if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,1,progress);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


        holder.sb_ipl_light_brightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean check) {
                Log.e("彩光 亮度",progress+"  "+ check);
                holder.tv_ipl_light_brightness.setText(progress+"%");
                if(check){
                    if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,2,progress);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        holder.sb_ipl_light_saturation.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean check) {
                Log.e("彩光 饱和度",progress+"  "+ check);
                holder.tv_ipl_light_saturation_1.setText(progress+"%");
                if(check){
                    if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,3,progress);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        holder.sb_color.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean check) {
                Log.e("彩光 色彩角度",progress+"  "+ check);
                holder.tv_ipl_h.setText("H: " + progress+"°");
                if(check){
                    if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,4,progress);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


        holder.tv_group.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("点击 组别", "!");
                if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                    onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,5,-1);
                }
            }
        });


        holder.iv_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("开关", open[0] +"");
                open[0] = !open[0];
                holder.iv_close.setImageResource(open[0] ? R.mipmap.open:R.mipmap.close);
                if(onItemClickListener!=null){
                    onItemClickListener.onItemIconClickListener(select,6, open[0] ?1:0);
                }
            }
        });



        DeviceInfo deviceInfo = deviceInfos.get(select);

        Glide.with(MyApplication.getInstance())
                .load(deviceInfo.getDevice_icon())
                .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new CircleCrop()))
                .into(holder.device_img);

        holder.device_name.setText(deviceInfo.getDevice_finally_name());

        switch (deviceInfo.getDeviceType()){
            case BaseConfig.DEVICE_1:
                DeviceBasicProperties_1 deviceBasicProperties1 = deviceInfo.getObject();
                w_brightness = deviceBasicProperties1.getWhite_light_brightness();
                w_temperature = deviceBasicProperties1.getWhite_light_temperature();
                i_brightness = deviceBasicProperties1.getIpl_light_brightness();
                i_saturation = deviceBasicProperties1.getIpl_light_saturation();
                i_color = deviceBasicProperties1.getIpl_light_h();
                open[0] = deviceBasicProperties1.isMain_switch();

                selectGroup =  deviceBasicProperties1.getGroup();
                selectChannel = deviceBasicProperties1.getChannel();

                cct_max = Config_1.CCT_MAX;
                cct_min = Config_1.CCT_MIN;

                holder.rel_temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.rel_ipl_brightness.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.rel_ipl_saturation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.rel_ipl_color.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case BaseConfig.DEVICE_2:
                DeviceBasicProperties_2 deviceBasicProperties2 = deviceInfo.getObject();
                w_brightness = deviceBasicProperties2.getWhite_light_brightness();
                w_temperature = deviceBasicProperties2.getWhite_light_temperature();
                i_brightness = deviceBasicProperties2.getIpl_light_brightness();
                i_saturation = deviceBasicProperties2.getIpl_light_saturation();
                i_color = deviceBasicProperties2.getIpl_light_h();
                open[0] = deviceBasicProperties2.isMain_switch();

                selectGroup =  deviceBasicProperties2.getGroup();
                selectChannel = deviceBasicProperties2.getChannel();

                cct_max = Config_2.CCT_MAX;
                cct_min = Config_2.CCT_MIN;


                holder.rel_temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.rel_ipl_brightness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rel_ipl_saturation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rel_ipl_color.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case BaseConfig.DEVICE_3:
                DeviceBasicProperties_3 deviceBasicProperties3 = deviceInfo.getObject();
                w_brightness = deviceBasicProperties3.getWhite_light_brightness();
                w_temperature = deviceBasicProperties3.getWhite_light_temperature();
                i_brightness = deviceBasicProperties3.getIpl_light_brightness();
                i_saturation = deviceBasicProperties3.getIpl_light_saturation();
                i_color = deviceBasicProperties3.getIpl_light_h();
                open[0] = deviceBasicProperties3.isMain_switch();

                selectGroup =  deviceBasicProperties3.getGroup();
                selectChannel = deviceBasicProperties3.getChannel();

                cct_max = Config_3.CCT_MAX;
                cct_min = Config_3.CCT_MIN;

                holder.rel_temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.rel_ipl_brightness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rel_ipl_saturation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rel_ipl_color.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case BaseConfig.DEVICE_4:
                DeviceBasicProperties_4 deviceBasicProperties4 = deviceInfo.getObject();
                w_brightness = deviceBasicProperties4.getWhite_light_brightness();
                w_temperature = deviceBasicProperties4.getWhite_light_temperature();
                i_brightness = deviceBasicProperties4.getIpl_light_brightness();
                i_saturation = deviceBasicProperties4.getIpl_light_saturation();
                i_color = deviceBasicProperties4.getIpl_light_h();
                open[0] = deviceBasicProperties4.isMain_switch();

                selectGroup =  deviceBasicProperties4.getGroup();
                selectChannel = deviceBasicProperties4.getChannel();

                holder.rel_temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.rel_ipl_brightness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rel_ipl_saturation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rel_ipl_color.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }

        holder.sb_white_light_brightness.setProgress(w_brightness);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            holder.sb_white_light_color_temperature.setMin(cct_min);
        }else {
            setProgressMin(holder.sb_white_light_color_temperature,cct_min);
        }
        holder.sb_white_light_color_temperature.setMax(cct_max);

        holder.sb_white_light_color_temperature.setProgress(w_temperature);

        holder.sb_ipl_light_brightness.setProgress(i_brightness);

        holder.sb_ipl_light_saturation.setProgress(i_saturation);

        holder.sb_color.setProgress(i_color);

        holder.tv_group.setText(" Grp:"+BaseConfig.GROUP_NUMBER[selectGroup]+" Ch:"+BaseConfig.CHANNEL_NUMBER[selectChannel]);

        holder.iv_close.setImageResource(open[0] ? R.mipmap.open:R.mipmap.close);

        return convertView;
    }


    public abstract static class OnItemClickListener{
        public abstract void onItemIconClickListener(int selected,int viewId,int value);
    }



    public void setProgressMin(ProgressBar progressBar,int min){
        // 检查setMin方法是否存在
        Method setMinMethod;
        try {
            setMinMethod = progressBar.getClass().getMethod("setMin", int.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.w("ProgressBarCompat", "setMin method not found, using default behavior");
            // 如果找不到setMin方法，可以在这里设置默认行为，比如min = 0
            return;
        }

        try {
            setMinMethod.invoke(progressBar, min);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e("ProgressBarCompat", "Failed to set progress bar minimum value", e);
        }
    }
}


Please anyone help me.
I am here using the view holder where we use the seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener in it only when we touch then it works but not the onProgressChange works with the dragging.
Please any one tell me what am I wrong.
onProgressChanged called only on the click not on dragging.
Seekbar slider not works on dragging works only on when we click.

I think you need to handle
onStartTrackingTouch() and
onStopTrackingTouch()
methods, try putting some logs in this method

Thanks for helping!. But the single time value print on touch only. not on dragging onStartTrackingTouch() and onStopTrackingTouch() methods.

I was using the swipemenulistview package, which causes the issue. In that there is a function called onIntercepTouchEvent() method which overrides the dragging features to the touch event. On removing that it works well.
